# Recent Node.js polyfill to EcmaScript 2015

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

So with **Node.js 6+**, April 26, 2016 or later, there is 96% [Node.js EcmaScript 2015 support](http://node.green).

Is the best way to fill in that last 4% still [babel](https://babeljs.io)? Like allowing to run and debug with like node-inspector?

```js
require("babel-core/register")
new (require('./lib/myes2015').FancyClass)()
```

Babel is sort of slow to start and claims to not be for production.

[Node.js Releases](https://nodejs.org/en/download/releases/)

Comment: Are you really getting 100% from Babel?  I'd say you look at what node.js 6 is missing and first decide if that missing 4% are actually relevant or can be coded around or can be polyfilled individually.  When I scan the chart is looks like almost 1/3 of the issues are one issue called "iterator closing".

Comment: So we're stuck with babel until v8 gets to 100%, which is like Node.js 8

However, you are supposed to use babel-cli and babel-polyfill.

For interested parties, search for something like this:
npm install webpack-dev-server webpack babel-loader babel-core babel-preset-es2015 babel-polyfill --save-dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still at 98% we need Babel. For example import is not in Node.js 6.2